# How can I remote control Ubuntu from a Mac?

Tags: reboot, remote

So I am going out of town for a month and want to be able to control my Ubuntu from my MacBook Pro since it will be mining litecoins and I want to be able to make sure it starts up/works correctly if something happens (power outage, server goes down, etc).

How do I go about this?

What do I need to do to get my computer to reboot automatically since I wouldn't be able to access Ubuntu if the computer is off (right?)? Is that in the BIOS?

What steps do I need to do in order to access the computer from my Mac?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your BIOS and Network Configuration.

From your BIOS, look for the option to restore from `AC Power Loss` normally containing

**Restore from AC power loss [always off | always on | last state]**.

I normally put it to last state, so if there is a power loss when it is off it will remain off, however if it is on during the power loss, it will automatically turn on when power comes back.

Also, you can enable the Wake on LAN feature on your BIOS if you can remotely access your router. For that, read : [WakeOnLan](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WakeOnLan)

To access your Ubuntu from a Mac, you may need to install a remote control software like [TeamViewer](http://teamviewer.com).

Goodluck.